# How to get rid of an intermediate array in this case?

Tags: javascript

I have this this function (I think the code is self-explanatory):

```
items: function(input) {                                                                                                                            
    let arr = [];                                                                                                                               
    for(let i=0; i<input.length; i++){                                                                                                              
         if(input[i].quantity > 0) {                                                                                                                 
             arr.push({                                                                                                                      
                 value: false,                                                                                                                                
                 name: input[i].name,                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
             });                                                                                                                                              
          }                                                                                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                        
   return arr;                                                                                                                             
},
```

I wonder if there is a shorter way to do it without relying on the intermediate `arr`?

Comment: if you dont want another array then do you want to change the input? if so you could try using .map()

Comment: Higher order functions like `map`, `reduce`, or `filter` could work I guess.

Comment: You can use $.each( obj, function( key, value ) { });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use Array built in methods:

```
items: (input) => input
        .filter(({ quantity }) => quantity > 0)
        .map(({ name }) => ({ name, value: false }))
```

Comment: This solution doesn't affect the original input, but instantiates a new array with the mapped values. See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for further information

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You'll *have* to create an array regardless (need something to be returned, after all), but one option is to immediately return a call to `reduce`:

```
items: input => input.reduce((a, { name, quantity }) => {
  if (quantity > 0) a.push({ value: false, name });
  return a;
}, []))
```

This is similar to what could be accomplished with a `.filter` followed by a `.map`, but `.filter` followed by `.map` will require the unnecessary construction of an intermediate array, and requires iterating over some input elements twice, rather than once.

Answer (score 1):

Your code combines filtering and transforming. You only want to keep elements whose `quantity` is positive, and you want to transform them to `{value: false, name: ...}` objects.

This can be done by combining `filter` and `map`:

```
items: function(input) {
    return (
        input
            .filter(function (x) { return x.quantity > 0; })
            .map(function(x) { return { value: false, name: x.name }; })
    );                                                                                                  
}
```

You can fuse the two operations by using `reduce`:

```
items: function(input) {
    return (
        input
            .reduce(function (z, x) {
                return (
                    x.quantity > 0
                        ? z.concat({value: false, name: x.name})
                        : z
                );
            }, [])
    );                                                                                                  
}
```

This only traverses `input` once, but constructs many intermediate arrays (via `concat`).

You can "cheat" by writing an imperative loop that modifies an accumulator array in place (like your `arr`), but disguise it as a `reduce`:

```
items: function(input) {
    return (
        input
            .reduce(function (arr, x) {
                if (x.quantity > 0) {
                    arr.push({value: false, name: x.name});
                }
                return arr;
            }, [])
    );                                                                                                  
}
```

Here we still have an intermediate `arr`, but its definition is hidden / distributed between `function (arr, x)`, `return arr`, and `[]` at the end.

It is functionally equivalent to:

```
items: function(input) {
    var arr = [];  // used to be function (arr, ...) ..., []
    input.reduce(function (_, x) {
        if (x.quantity > 0) {
            arr.push({value: false, name: x.name});
        }
    }, undefined);
    return arr;  // used to be inside the reduce call
}
```

which really just uses `reduce` to iterate over the input elements, so it could be written as

```
items: function(input) {
    var arr = [];
    input.forEach(function (x) {
        if (x.quantity > 0) {
            arr.push({value: false, name: x.name});
        }
    });
    return arr;
}
```

which is pretty much your original code.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an array to store the returned object. Your code could be rewritten as :

```
items: input => {
    const a = input.map(i => {
        if (i.quantity > 0) {
          return {name: i.name, value: false};
        }
    })
    return a;
}
```